# Migrating JavaScript code to node.js modules with String.prototype extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope, prototype

I'm trying to migrate Crockfords TDOP based parser to Node.js, as I want to use it as a base for my own parser.

In his code he extends the String object with a new method called "tokens":

```
String.prototype.tokens = function (prefix, suffix) {
[...]
```

Source: https://github.com/douglascrockford/TDOP/blob/master/tokens.js#L25

This method gets called by his parser later:

```
[...]

return function (source) {
    tokens = source.tokens('=<>!+-*&|/%^', '=<>&|');
    token_nr = 0;
    new_scope();
    advance();
    var s = statements();
    advance("(end)");
    scope.pop();
    return s;
};

[...]
```

Source: https://github.com/douglascrockford/TDOP/blob/master/parse.js#L520

In the browser version he simply loads all those files which seem to be added to the global scope so all works fine:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/TDOP/blob/master/index.html#L58

I'm now trying to get this to work in Node. For that I started stripping out the stuff which is browser based and read a sample file from filesystem.

It seems to do something up to the point where the String.tokens method gets called, in there I get `'my string' has no method 'tokens'`. In my limited understanding of scopes I suspect that this is because node seems to create its own "global" scope for each module. My big question now is how can I extend the String object in a way that this will work out? I tried defining this method in many different scopes in my sample code but I couldn't get a single one of them to work. My idea is to have the parse method as a module and then assign `String.prototype.tokens == mymodule.tokens` from that file.

Is this the right approach and if so, where the heck do I have to define the `String.prototype.tokens` method that my code will be able to find it?

I've created a github repository with my node code, pull requests are welcome ;)

https://github.com/ktk/js-scope-test/blob/master/node.js

Comment: For what it's worth, I strongly recommend not extending objects like that.  I've done it before on something I thought for sure would be harmless, and got bitten pretty hard with weird issues that took quite a while to track down.

Comment: Some quick tests make it appear that extending a native object in one module will have the same effect in any module that imports it (I'm running v0.10, for what it's worth). Where precisely are you trying to call 'tokens' on a string? I can't see such a call in your code anywhere; just the addition of the method at the start of parse.js.

Comment: The call is here: https://github.com/ktk/js-scope-test/blob/master/parse.js#L528

Comment: @Bubbles you were right, this is supposed to work. And guess what, it does work. My code had a bug, I passed a Buffer instead of a String so there was indeed no tokens method. Damn... :) Will close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did work all the time as Bubbles pointed out. I forgot to call toString() on the Buffer object I got from fs.readFile...

Sorry & thanks for the hints.